# Asterisk module in OpenERP can not connect to elastix server

Tags: odoo, asterisk, openerp-7

I installed `asterisk_click2dial` and `asterisk_click2dial_crm` in my OpenERP 7.0. And set all configurations for company and users section.

But whenever I click on dial button in form, Error dialog opened and show

```
"error: Connection refused".
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need also configure it.

Most likly it have config file with manager connection info.

Manager config file /etc/asterisk/manager.conf. You have put same login/password in both places